# source of a phrase found on a tombstone

Tags: talmud-gemara, humor

Does anyone know the source for the phrase "a person who dispenses humor will be in the kingdom of heaven, for he has lessened the sadness of human life"? It was cited as Taanit 22b, but is not there. I wonder if it is from another source or totally fictitious.

Answer (score 4):

It’s probably a typo for 22a, but if it is, it’s not a direct quote.

> א"ל הנך נמי בני עלמא דאתי נינהו אזל לגבייהו אמר להו מאי עובדייכו אמרו ליה אינשי בדוחי אנן מבדחינן עציבי אי נמי כי חזינן בי תרי דאית להו תיגרא בהדייהו טרחינן ועבדינן להו שלמא:
>
> [Eliyahu HaNavi] said to [R’ Beroka], “These [two men] also have a share in the World to Come.” [R’ Beroka] went to them. He said to them, “What do you do?” They said to him, “We are jesters, and we cheer up the depressed, or when we see two people arguing, we make peace between them.”

Perhaps the quote refers to the first thing these men did, as they specifically dispensed humor to those who were depressed, and they merited a share in the World to Come as a result.

Comment: To the downvoter: care to explain?